# Pass a parameter to Facebook Page Tab app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page, facebook-iframe

I have this HTML on this URL: https://myapp.herokuapp.com

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe frameborder=0 border=0 scrolling="no" src="<?php echo $_GET['url']; ?>" width="760px" height="521px"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

I have created a Facebook Page Tab and I want that anyone can install it on their Facebook Page with a different URL. So when you click on the tab on FB Page 1 it would display embedded URL1, FB Page 2 would display URL2, and so on. The URL is, then, a parameter when you install the Page Tab.

I have tried this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=XXXXXXXXXX&next=https://myapp.herokuapp.com?url=HERE_YOUR_URL
```

It is installing the app, but seems that the URL parameter in the iframe is null. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: The next URL is just where you go to next. Not the url that is installed. The URL that is installed is the one that is defined in the Developer App Settings

Comment: So if I want to create thes Page Tab apps dinamically, each one with a different parameter, I can't do it?

Comment: I don't think this is possible

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My approach is a little different.

While it may not be possible to install Apps with URL parameters, you could adjust their content depending on which Page loaded them in the first place. As the Page Tab Facebook API Integration Tutorial states:

> When a user selects your Page Tab, you will receive the **signed_request** 
>       parameter with one additional parameter, **page**. This parameter contains 
>       a JSON object with an **id** (the page id of the current page) ([SOURCE](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/#integrating))

So you would install the **same** App on **several** pages, and use the following code at the top (after you've created the `$facebook` object):

```
$page_id = "";
$sr = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
if($page = $sr['page']) {
    $page_id = $page['id'];
}
```

You should now be able to use `$page_id` as the unique identifier telling you which page the user is currently viewing the application from, instead of a `$_GET` variable. `Switch` statements or a database integration are the first methods that come to mind, but you seem to be asking how to **identify and retrieve** a unique parameter and not how to **use** it, so I'm sure you will figure this out on your own. :)

Note: This (obviously) will not work on an app being installed on several Page Tabs of the **same page**, but that doesn't seem to be a concern of yours.

Comment: Very good. That was what I was about to edit my answer to as well :-)

Comment: +1 - That's the recommended method in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/#integrating

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding it's not possible to have on app installed in separate Page tabs. You'll need to create different apps for that, but you can use use the same "base app" location and augment the location with your desired parameters.

For example:

1. You create two apps with "Page Tab" as platform.
2. For the first app, specify a Page Tab URL `https://myapp.herokuapp.com/index.php?test=1`
3. For the first app, specify a Page Tab URL `https://myapp.herokuapp.com/index.php?test=2`
4. Create an `index.php` in your apps base folder:

   `<? echo $_GET["test"]; ?>`
5. Add both Page Tab apps to a Page (or separate Pages). See:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page/tabs/#publish or  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/
6. Open first Page Tab, then second, and see that diffent parameter results are shown

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I really need to have a single app, I cannot afford creating hundreds of them. For instance, TwitterTab does what I need to do, have your personal data in your tab. https://www.facebook.com/ZapatosCastellano/app_142847962439861 How can I do that?

Comment: There are no such restrictions with Facebook Apps. I know from personal experience that an app can be installed on several pages, I've had 3+. Due to "From my undestanding..." I see no reason to downvote this, however.

Comment: I meant one app at several Page tabs of the same Page... And, he wants to pass a URL parameter. How would you do that then?

Comment: Ah, well that may very well be impossible. And yeh, the URL parameter is the tough nut to crack. :)